# The right way to expose a complex short-lived object

Tags: c++, pointers, binding

I am developing a Darwinian evolution simulation. For performance reasons, it's written in C++. The sim is represented by an instance of World. The animals are represented by instances of Animal, a fairly complicated object. World has two important methods:

```
animal_at(int i)
```

and

```
evolve(int n).
```

animal_at returns a non-null raw pointer to the instance of Animal that represents the i-th animal.
evolve advances the simulation possibly **invalidating any pointer returned by animal_at**.
I want to make the sim and the animals easily accessible from outside. I have python-specific bindings, but i'm considering learning CORBA or Ice to implement a more generic interface. The problem is how I should expose the animals. I have two ideas, none of which feels satisfactory:
1) Rewrite the code slightly to use shared_ptr instead of a raw ptr and use a middleware that understands shared_ptr semantics.
2) Generate a "deep lazy proxy" that has the same structure as Animal. Its members would be proxies to members of Animal, recursively. animal_at would be actually called in the last moment before referring to the actual data -- the pointer would be used and immediately tossed away. This would implement the "last moment" semantics.

I dislike 1) because I would have to introduce a "zombie" state of the object, which looks inelegant to me.
I dislike 2) because the sole purpose of the proxy is to implement the "last moment" semantics.

I am looking for an automatic non-intrusive way (using code-generation) to achieve this, because I don't want to obscure the meaning of the original code. Is there any "official" name for what I call "last moment" semantics?

Answer (score 2):

There is an option of using boost::weak_ptr. You can pass these around, they have to use lock() to get the underlying shared_ptr so they can see if the object no longer exists.

The lifetime of the object is determined only by the places where a shared_ptr is held. There must therefore be at least one of these at all times during the lifetime of the object, and you need one before you can create a weak_ptr.

Comment: I'll have a closer look at boost::weak_ptr. The question is, how will this interplay with CORBA. I don't want to learn CORBA just to find out that "no, CORBA doesn't support last moment semantics". Thanks for the reply.

Comment: CORBA uses its own reference-counting with _var and does not support a concept of a weak pointer. I think if you use an object that no longer exists on the server side you get an exception rather than a crash. With CORBA the concept is that the whole server could go down. There is such a thing as a Transient exception where the server is down but the objects were created with "persistence" such that they will exist when it comes back up again.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you might consider [xml-rpc](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/) instead of CORBA as middleware (more standard use nowadays).

Secondly, external users work with marshalled data.  They send a marshalled reference over the middleware and expect marshalled information based on their request and reference, so I don't see how this works together with "last moment" sementics and pointers.  You either keep all your temporary animals, so external users can query them or you probably have to send a lot exceptions for not found animals.  (or you let them request the "latest" animal)

Comment: For performance reasons, I do not intend to marshall the whole animal. I want the external user to be able to modify individual members, members of members, maybe even invoke methods of members of members etc. Is xml-rpc suited for "natural" communication with C++ objects?

Comment: If the reference is the index i of the animal (the same index may refer to different animals at different times), I have to generate the "deep proxy" boilerplate (I refuse to write boilerplate by hand for ideological reasons). If the reference is bound to the identity of the object, the server part of the middleware has to be able to determine, whether the object still exists (so it should use boost::weak_ptr or so).

Comment: xml-rpc is not as "natural" as corba for objects, but in the end objects are also passed by its corba object-reference, so per member, you would need an object that needs to be registered/unregistered and its reference must be passed.

Answer (score 1):

If your `animal_at` function returns a pointer that can be invalidated at any point in the future, you might try having it return a smart pointer (I'd suggest a `shared_ptr` over a `weak_ptr` here, but you can get away with the weak pointer if you are careful with the implementation).  However, instead of pointing directly to an `Animal` object, have it point to a `boost::optional<Animal>` object.  That way, when you invalidate the pointer, you can set the `invalid` flag on the pointer and any user of the newly invalidated object have the ability to check to see if they need to get a new pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the boost::optional hint, I'll look at it.

Comment: boost::optional here does the same that can be done by boost::weak_ptr. you store your boost::shared_ptr<Animal> in some central storage and return boost::weak_ptr<Animal> from animal_at. you just release shared_ptr to invalidate it. each time you want to use weak_ptr you need to "lock" it: if (boost::shared_ptr<Animal> animal = animal_weak_ptr.lock()) // pointer is still valid, use it

Comment: @Robin Hood:  I stated you could accomplish the same thing with `weak_ptr` is you were careful about the implementation.  Using a `shared_ptr<optional<Animal> >` simply makes it a bit more readable.  To check if the pointer is still valid (controlled by the managing object), a piece of client code would simply need to check the value of `p->valid`.  As always, there is more than 1 way to skin a cat ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't get why you want to export a pointer instead of exporting an interface which seems exactly the "last moment" semantics that you want. Your `animal_at` could return an object *id*, not a pointer, and the interface would give all the required access to the object, like `dosomething(id, params)`. The interface could also include lock/unlock stuff to enable atomic access.

Comment: Good point about the atomic access. By "deep proxy" I mean exactly this interface. Calls would look like animal_proxy(5).genome.genes[3].codones[6].dosomething(params) However, I don't know any tool to autogenerate such interface from the definition of Animal.

Comment: @Pavel: if your target is python, have you considered something like SWIG?

Comment: I already have working python bindings (made using Py++), but I would like to make the simulation a component any language can easily communicate with.

Comment: @Pavel: maybe I don't completely see what you want, but SWIG supports many languages and is quite commonly used

Comment: For Python, Py++ parses the C++ sources, so no need to repeat oneself writing the interface file. However, I want to make it a server which can be queried for the interface in a standard way (like CORBA's Interface Repository). I am still not sure whether 1) or 2) from my original question is more appropriate.